# How to send images captured on a webcam connected to Raspberry Pi to the cloud take an example of AWS?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a project where I need some assistance. I want to capture images through a webcam and for identification and classification I need to run a deep learning model on to the cloud, for this I need to send images from the webcam which is connected to RS Pi to the cloud. How can I do it? and which platform I need to use?

I'm expecting a solution where I get the clarity on how can I send images and also what I need to do after?

Answer (score -1):

(this is the typical python approach, you can also do this through shell and the https://aws.amazon.com/cli/, with the same aws tools)

The typical tool used for interacting with aws is [boto3](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/), if you want a serverless structure (not using a specific vm, but having aws abstractly allocate resources for you) you can use [awsLambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/category/compute/aws-lambda/) which you can call through [boto3lambda](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html), alternatively if you are using ec2 (aws's virtual machine provisioner) then you can upload your image to a [s3 bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), through [boto3s3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html) as well.